# facebook open graph debugger returning PARTIAL_FILE or operation_timeouted

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-opengraph, amazon-cloudfront, hapi.js

I'm trying to setup a facebook share on https://donate.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/share/

The og:url points to just /thunderbird which is the url I would want shared. Best I can tell the og tags are all there.

When I try to update the data on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

When I fetch new scrape information I get one of two errors. Initially, it'll take a long time then respond with a Curl Error : OPERATION_TIMEOUTED Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with {some number less than 10000} bytes received then subsequent fetch attempts respond with Curl Error : PARTIAL_FILE transfer closed with 17071 bytes remaining to read

We're using AWS Cloudfront and nodejs with hapijs

It responds with a 206 partial content, which, should be fine. The og tags are all in the beginning of the file.

I found this: docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RangeGETs.html

There it says a range request is used to get the file in chunks, not to get just the part of the file and give up. So maybe that's causing unexpected behavior. Maybe cloudfront is sending it back in chunks, and facebook stops listening after the first response? I dunno. Just trying to find a theory that fits the facts.

We already have a working share for donate.mozilla.org/en-US/share/ but that might be old data from when we were not using hapijs and instead using expressjs which I don't think was supporting range requests and would instead return a 200.

I'm mostly a front end dev, so a lot of this is out of my comfort zone but I have already learned a lot :)

Edit: I also want to point out we use Heroku for hosting, and if I setup a test with just heroku and without cloudfront: donate.mofostaging.net/en-US/thunderbird/ it fetches the tags successfully. So I suspect it's a bug when facebook and hapijs interact with cloudfront.

Comment: I think your theory is sound but it is possible that Facebook aren't even receiving anything because it seems that the debugger is saying that the majority of the og tags received are being inferred

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Sounds like you're saying some of the og props are incomplete and thus facebook is trying to figure it out, and failing?

I would be happen to add anything to the tags if it would make this work, but it's not clear what it's expecting. It does report that 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided. but to the best of my ability it's there.

I can also scrape that page while hosted in a different environment and it parses the tags fine.

Comment: Did you figured out what was the problem? I'm struggling with the same issue for a month now...